# jQuery selector: select anchor tags that are a descendants of a div with a particular id

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Trying to select anchor tags that are a descendants of a div with a particular id, say it is `#mydiv1`, `#mydiv2` and `#mydiv3`.

```
myFunction = function() {    
  var theDivs = $("#mydiv1, #mydiv2, #mydiv3");    
  theDivs.hover(function(e){    
      $(this+" a:link").css("color","#99ccff");
  },function(e){
      $(this+" a:link").css("color","#848484");        
  });    
}
```

The selector `$(this+" a:link")` doesn't seem to be selecting anything though.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the proper syntax for this selection?

Comment: so what you want is to change the color class of the link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give an element for context, the following should work:

```
$("a:link", this).
```

It will search for the anchors starting in `this` node.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably better. :)

Comment: Internally, providing context just calls find() after a chunk of case-checking code, meaning that calling find() directly is (very slightly) faster.

Comment: But using the 'Write less, do more' philosophy, I would favor this over my first answer. I think using find makes it a bit clearer what is wrong with the OP though.

Comment: I not 100% sure but I think that if you do $(this).find(), jQuery need to build the wrapper arround this first and therefore you'll loose the speed gain of calling find() directly.

Answer (score 10):

Try `$(this).find("a:link")`

EDIT: extra info

When you `$(this + "query")` you're mixing types. jQuery's selector param is looking for either a query string or an object. When 'this' gets converted to a string it isn't going to be valid selector syntax. For example, you *could* do something like this: 
`$("." + this.className + "[query]")`

Answer (score 1):

Or try `$(this).children("a:link")`

http://api.jquery.com/children/

Answer (score 0):

Either of the above methods should work, but I don't see anything in the jQuery selector syntax about ":link" being valid syntax.  Perhaps try leaving that off as well if the above methods don't work for you.

And the reason your original method didn't work is that "this" is a DOM element, not a string in your code.  As previously mentioned, you can make it a jQuery object by doing "$(this)" or just use the DOM element as the search context.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the divs with .each(), and use the child selector:

```
  myFunction = function() {    
      var theDivs = $("#mydiv1, #mydiv2, #mydiv3");    
  theDivs.each(function(){    
      $(this > 'a').css("color","#99ccff");
  });    
}
```

Like so.